# A-Frame: How and where to host 360 videos for smooth playback?

Tags: video, aframe, webvr

first timmer here,

I’m working on a VR Experience using A-frame. you can check it out here: https://basunderbuen.glitch.me/

I’m loading three 4k 360º videos but as you can see the videos are super laggy.

I’m looking for suggestions of how or where to host this videos so that they can run smoothly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear laggy at all for me. When 360 videos lag on a fast and stable server, it typically means that the user's internet connection is slow or the computer running the 360 video cannot handle the 4k video quality.

Only suggestion I can think of is to stream HD videos that are not in 4k resolution

Comment: Thanks, Brandon I have made an HD version now and it does run smoother. I guess I have to wait for the world's internet to be faster so we can stream 4k 360 videos.

Comment: Haha soon we'll have Google take over the world and give use Google Fiber. Glad I could help!